# CSS does not apply to a new element appended?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am new to HTML5 and I am doing a presentation using desk.js library to create it.
I added a toolbar to the page to be able to add new slide and so on, in my JavaScript code I wrote a function that appends an element `<section>` to a div with the class "slide" which permits to create the style of the slide, but the slide or `<section>` is added to the 1st one and doesn't have the functionalities `<section class="slide">` have.

Any suggestions??

Js code:

```
function addSlide(){
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    console.log("creating");
    var element = document.createElement("section");
    element.className = "slide";
    container.appendChild(element);
    console.log("created")
}
```

deck.js
http://imakewebthings.com/deck.js/

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. http://jsfiddle.net/SR35Y/

Comment: Did you inspect the page to see if the slide is created at the right place? Not having functionality from the js is not the same thing as css class not applied. Which issue are you actually having?

Comment: Clarification - do you want `<div id="container"><section class="slide">` or `<div id="container" class="slide"><section>`?  The question could be read either way, and the former is what your code does.

Comment: Also, are you calling `$.deck()` before or after addSlide?

Comment: I just read some of the dock and I think you need to add your slides before the initialization `deck.beforeInit` http://imakewebthings.com/deck.js/docs/#deck-core-events the docs shows how to lock initialization and do whatever you need to do then intialize.

Comment: @cxw i want <div id="container"><section class="slide">, $.deck('slide') is called at the end of the html page so when the event happens its not called

Comment: @Huangism can you give me an example because this happens depending on the user's action.

Comment: Found why css didn't apply on the new slide added, had to reinitialize the deck by adding at the end.

    $.deck('.slide');

Comment: @user3197607 - glad to hear it!  Would you please post this as an answer and then accept it once the system will let you?  That way this question won't appear in the Unanswered list.  Thanks!